# Closure Compiler - warning: restricted index type found:string, required:number

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I get this warning:

```
WARNING - restricted index type

found   : string
required: number

someArray[ index ].doSomething();
```

This happens after a closure compiler upgrade to the latest version.
It looks like the use of a string type indexes for arrays are not recommended by closure compiler.

What would be the recommended solution to this problem?

BTW. Is there a way to disable check for these warning types (I looked through the CC flags list and can't find anything)?

Comment: You can put `/** @suppress {checkTypes} */` just before the function containing this code. Or you can cast `index` to a number.

Answer (score 0):

If your index variable is of type string, you should parse it first.
Try

```
someArray[parseInt(index)].doSomething();
```

Additionally, I assume that the reason it's a string in the first place is that it comes from somewhere like a DOM attribute or an HTML input. You might want to make sure the value is valid, before using it.

```
const parsedIndex = parseInt(index);
if (isNaN(parsedIndex) || index < 0) {
  throw 'Invalid index';
}
someArray[parsedIndex].doSomething();
```